# Capture actual rsync error

Tags: rsync

We are transferring files from local (Windows) to a remote system (Unix). On several setups we are getting Error Code #13. The man page says that it is `Errors with program diagnostics`.

On our systems, we know that one possible cause is directory permissions on the remote server and the other is that port 873 is not open.

Is there a distinct way to determine which is the cause of the error? Is it possible to check for the port, first, return an error if encountered, and then begin the transfer?

I would think that `rsync` would have more granular error codes, especially when it comes to the actual connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate by asking `rsync` for a directory listing of the remote system.

1. Server responding correctly within two seconds

   ```
   $ rsync --contimeout=2 remoteserver::
   SHARE1          We store stuff here
   SHARE2          we store other stuff here
   $ echo $?
   0
   ```
2. Server not running an `rsync` daemon

   ```
   $ rsync --contimeout=2 remoteserver::
   rsync: failed to connect to remoteserver (10.10.10.10): Connection refused (111)
   rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [Receiver=3.1.2]
   $ echo $?
   10
   ```
3. Server not responding within two seconds

   ```
   $ rsync --contimeout=2 remoteserver::
   rsync error: timeout waiting for daemon connection (code 35) at socket.c(281) [Receiver=3.1.2]
   $ echo $?
   35
   ```